# 'ApplicationDbContext' does not inherit from DbContext

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-3.1

I´m getting this error:

The type `ApplicationDbContext` does not inherit from `DbContext`. The `DbMigrationsConfiguration.ContextType` property must be set to a type that inherits from `DbContext`.

This is my code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Manufactura.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Categories> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CustomerCities> CustomerCities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CustomerCountries> CustomerCountries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CustomerRegions> CustomerRegions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customers> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Employees> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Payments> Payments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductDetails> ProductDetails { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductionOrders> ProductionOrders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Products> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RawMaterials> RawMaterials { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SaleInvoices> SaleInvoices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Shippings> Shippings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SuplierCities> SuplierCities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SuplierCountries> SuplierCountries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SuplierInvoices> SuplierInvoices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SuplierRegions> SuplierRegions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Supliers> Supliers { get; set; }
        

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            // optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SchoolDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Categories>().HasKey(m => m.CategoryId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerCities>().HasKey(m => m.CustomerCity);
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerCountries>().HasKey(m => m.CustomerCountry);
            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerRegions>().HasKey(m => m.CustomerRegion);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customers>().HasKey(m => m.CustomerId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employees>().HasKey(m => m.EmployeeId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Payments>().HasKey(m => m.PaymentId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductDetails>().HasKey(m => m.ProductDetailsId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductionOrders>().HasKey(m => m.ProductionOrdersId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Products>().HasKey(m => m.ProductId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<RawMaterials>().HasKey(m => m.RawMaterialsId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<SaleInvoices>().HasKey(m => m.SaleInvoiceId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Shippings>().HasKey(m => m.ShippingId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<SuplierCities>().HasKey(m => m.SuplierCity);
            modelBuilder.Entity<SuplierCountries>().HasKey(m => m.SuplierCountry);
            modelBuilder.Entity<SuplierInvoices>().HasKey(m => m.SuplierInvoiceId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<SuplierRegions>().HasKey(m => m.SuplierRegion);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Supliers>().HasKey(m => m.SuplierId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Products>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Category)
            .WithMany(b => b.Products);

            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerRegions>()
           .HasOne(p => p.CustomerCountry)
           .WithMany(b => b.CustomerRegions);

            modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerCities>()
           .HasOne(p => p.CustomerRegion)
           .WithMany(b => b.CustomerCities);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customers>()
           .HasOne(p => p.CustomerCity)
           .WithMany(b => b.Customers);

            modelBuilder.Entity<SaleInvoices>()
           .HasOne(p => p.Customer)
           .WithMany(b => b.SaleInvoices);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Payments>()
           .HasOne(p => p.SaleInvoice)
           .WithMany(b => b.Payments);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductDetails>()
           .HasOne(p => p.SaleInvoice)
           .WithMany(b => b.ProductDetails);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Products>()
           .HasOne(p => p.ProductDetail)
           .WithMany(b => b.Products);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Products>()
           .HasOne(p => p.ProductionOrder)
           .WithMany(b => b.Products);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Products>()
           .HasOne(p => p.Employee)
           .WithMany(b => b.Products);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Products>()
           .HasOne(p => p.Category)
           .WithMany(b => b.Products);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ProductionOrders>()
           .HasOne(p => p.RawMaterial)
           .WithMany(b => b.ProductionOrders);

            modelBuilder.Entity<SuplierInvoices>()
           .HasOne(p => p.RawMaterial)
           .WithMany(b => b.SuplierInvoices);

            modelBuilder.Entity<SuplierInvoices>()
           .HasOne(p => p.Suplier)
           .WithMany(b => b.SuplierInvoices);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Supliers>()
           .HasOne(p => p.SuplierCity)
           .WithMany(b => b.Supliers);

            modelBuilder.Entity<SuplierCities>()
           .HasOne(p => p.SuplierRegion)
           .WithMany(b => b.SuplierCities);

            modelBuilder.Entity<SuplierRegions>()
           .HasOne(p => p.SuplierCountry)
           .WithMany(b => b.SuplierRegions);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

    }
}
```

I´ve tried all that this site says, including restarting VS:

```
enable-migrations -ProjectName Manufactura -Verbose

Enable-Migrations -ProjectName Manufactura -ContextTypeName Manufactura.Models.ApplicationDbContext

Enable-Migrations -ProjectName Manufactura -ContextTypeName Manufactura.Models.ApplicationDbContext -force

Install-Package EntityFramework -IncludePrerelease

UnInstall-Package EntityFramework 

Install-Package EntityFramework
```

This an application of **.Net Core 3.1** in **VS 2019**

If I uncomment `System.Data.Entity`, i get the error: `DbContext` is an ambiguous reference

Nothing works.

This is my appsettings

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionString": "Data Source=.;Initial catalog=confecciones;Integrated Security=true"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Usin f12 on DbContext, it take me here:

```
namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
ublic class DbContext : IDisposable, IAsyncDisposable, IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>, IDbContextDependencies, IDbSetCache, IDbContextPoolable, IResettableService
    {
        //
        // Resumen:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext class
        //     using the specified options. The Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.OnConfiguring(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder)
        //     method will still be called to allow further configuration of the options.
        //
        // Parámetros:
        //   options:
        //     The options for this context.
        public DbContext([NotNullAttribute] DbContextOptions options);
        //
        // Resumen:
        //     Initializes a new instance of the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext class.
        //     The Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.OnConfiguring(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder)
        //     method will be called to configure the database (and other options) to be used
        //     for this context.
        protected DbContext();
```

Startup code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
//using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Manufactura.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Manufactura
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddRazorPages();
                        
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString")));
            services.AddControllers();

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Appsettings:

```
{


  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ConnectionString": "Data Source=DESKTOP-APHO8VE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial catalog=confecciones;Integrated Security=true"
  }
}
```

Comment: You are most likely referencing the wrong DbContext, put the cursor on it and hit F12 to verify.

Comment: It takes me here: namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: Try removing the regular Entity framework package from your packages, feel free to message me a github-link if you are still stuck after that.

Comment: Hi, I tried that several times... I even just uninstalled VS and installed again

Comment: Reproduce the issue in a new project to verify, I can't reproduce it...

Comment: On a new project the error is: No context type was found in the assembly. Can you share the link of the project you have made and that doesnt have the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216555/discussion-between-notimplementedexception-and-hernandez400).

Answer (score 1):

After what @LJH said,
I was using the same name for the migration over and over, i´ve changed it and i´ve used too a short version of add-migration and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have EntityFrameworkCore and EntityFramework 6.x (or pre-.NET Core version) in the same solution: System.Data.Entity namespace is for EF6 etc.

If you must use the 2 versions together, Microsoft recommends being more explicit with your namespaces:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/side-by-side

Comment: I don´t need two... only one, wich should I use? Im trying to create a software for a small company

Comment: I would and do use Entity Framework Core. Uninstall EF6 and install EF Core with its tools etc.  Use `uninstall-package Microsoft.EntityFramework` to uninstall earlier versions, and `install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` for EF Core.

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFramework' to uninstall not found in project, I´ve installed the other one. After enable-migrations, the error No context type was found in the assembly, appears

Comment: I thought `Enable-migrations` is not used in EF Core - you use `Add-Migration`.  If you have more than one project, make sure the project that has EF6 possibly installed, is set as the startup project, then go to Package Manager Console and run `uninstall-package Entityframework`.  I  incorrectly stated `Microsoft.Entityframework` previously.

Comment: I´ve done what you said, this error comes up: Your target project 'Manufactura' doesn't reference EntityFramework. This package is required for the Entity Framework Core Tools to work. Ensure your target project is correct, install the package, and try again.